# keepalived works well without iptables

Tags: iptables

I have setup keepalived, and it works well only when I stop the iptables service. My iptables config like this, Please tell me what rules should added for keepalived

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22   -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80   -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 5666 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 5):

You must accept ip protocol 112 (vrrp) and multicast traffic to 224.0.0.18. If you are using auth_type AH then you must accept proto 51

```
iptables -I INPUT -p 112 -d 224.0.0.18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p 51  -d 224.0.0.18 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That AH rule is crutial and it's the only place where it's mentioned...

Comment: I executed that command in my computer "iptables -I INPUT -p 112 -d 224.0.0.18 -j ACCEPT" but now I need to revoke it, how can I do that?

Comment: @EmrahTema "iptables -D INPUT -p 112 -d 224.0.0.18 -j ACCEPT"

Answer (score 4):

Just slove this problem these days,Haha

Do:

```
iptables -I INPUT -d 224.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p vrrp -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Is that 1st rule right?  Without `-p` it defaults to `tcp`, which isn't used in multicast.

Answer (score 1):

to MASTER keepalived machine:

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p vrrp -s 192.168.10.1 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

to BACKUP keepalived machine:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p vrrp -s 192.168.10.1  -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

192.168.10.1 is the master keepalived ip